# React-Webcam isn't displayed on other devices on same Wifi network

Tags: reactjs, android-camera, webcam, ios-camera

I'm trying to make a web-app that shows a video stream of the user's webcam if they're on a laptop or the back-camera if accessing the browser through a mobile device. Using the react-webcam library to do this (https://github.com/mozmorris/react-webcam).

It works fine on the device I'm running npm on, but other devices (tried on a different laptop and Android/IOS device) on the network don't show the webcam view and only the Start Capture button.

Code:
Camera.js

```
import React from "react";
import Webcam from "react-webcam";

function Camera(){
    const webcamRef = React.useRef(null);
    const mediaRecorderRef = React.useRef(null);
    const [capturing, setCapturing] = React.useState(false);
    const [recordedChunks, setRecordedChunks] = React.useState([]);

    const handleStartCaptureClick = React.useCallback(() => {
        setCapturing(true);
        mediaRecorderRef.current = new MediaRecorder(webcamRef.current.stream, {
            mimeType: "video/webm"
        });
        mediaRecorderRef.current.addEventListener(
            "dataavailable",
            handleDataAvailable
        );
        mediaRecorderRef.current.start();
    }, [webcamRef, setCapturing, mediaRecorderRef]);

    const handleDataAvailable = React.useCallback(
        ({ data }) => {
            if (data.size > 0) {
            setRecordedChunks((prev) => prev.concat(data));
            }
        },[setRecordedChunks]
    );

    const handleStopCaptureClick = React.useCallback(() => {
        mediaRecorderRef.current.stop();
        setCapturing(false);
    }, [mediaRecorderRef, webcamRef, setCapturing]);

    const handleDownload = React.useCallback(() => {
        if (recordedChunks.length) {
            const blob = new Blob(recordedChunks, {
            type: "video/webm"
            });
            const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            const a = document.createElement("a");
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.style = "display: none";
            a.href = url;
            a.download = "react-webcam-stream-capture.webm";
            a.click();
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
            setRecordedChunks([]);
        }
    }, [recordedChunks]);

    return (
        <>
            <Webcam audio={false} ref={webcamRef} />
            {capturing ? 
                (<button onClick={handleStopCaptureClick}>Stop Capture</button>) : 
                (<button onClick={handleStartCaptureClick}>Start Capture</button>)}
            {recordedChunks.length > 0 && 
                (<button onClick={handleDownload}>Download</button>)}
        </>
    );
}

export default Camera;
```

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import Webcam from 'react-webcam';

import './index.css';
import Camera from './Camera';

//ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <Camera />
    </React.StrictMode>
);
```

I believe it might have to do with permissions since the other devices don't show a popup to allow camera access, but I'm not sure how to manually ask for permissions to enable it to work.

Appreciate any help or suggesstions, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I've had a similiar problem recently to which the solution was that HTTPS-configuration was needed for it to work. If it's not already configured for HTTPS, temporarily, if using chrome, you could try to input the URL to your page as a chrome flag right here (this should be done on the client, aka the laptop/phone):

chrome://flags/#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure

and it will treat the page as a secure context. I wouldn't recommend keeping it like that unless it's for testing the camera only.

Comment: That actually worked like a charm, would the next viable step be to actually configure the web-app to be configurable for HTTPS?

Comment: Yes that would be the next step, unfortunately I'm not the guy who solved the actual configuration so I can't tell you how to.

Comment: To actually configure the web-app to be configurable for HTTPS, add this to your .htaccess:          `RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]`